# Why is my Material UI Tabs component overwriting other styles at random?

Tags: css, material-ui, tabs, modal-dialog

I have a react app with a dashboard that you navigate with Material UI Tabs. One of the tabs has a button that opens a modal to add new users to the system. The modal also uses Tabs within itself. However, despite how I have tried to style/format the tabs in the modal, it causes seemingly random issues with the rest of the app's styling, depending on which tab is active. The relevant code in my modal is this:

```
function TabPanel(props: any) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `create-user-modal-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `create-user-modal-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

...

return(
<div>
      <Tabs
      value={indexValue}
      onChange={handleChange}
      aria-label="create user modal tabs">
        <Tab label="Single User" {...a11yProps(0)} />
        <Tab label="Multi User" {...a11yProps(1)} />
        <Tab label="CSV Import" {...a11yProps(2)} />
      </Tabs>
      <TabPanel value={indexValue} index={0}>
        <SingleUserTab />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={indexValue} index={1}>
        <MultiUserTab />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={indexValue} index={2}>
        <CSVImportTab />
      </TabPanel>
</div>
)
```

I have tried configuring nearly all the properties of Tabs, including `classes`, `text color` `variant`, etc. My only partial success so far has been to make the modal Tabs into a `styled(Tabs)` component...but this only seems to work when the first tab (...a11yProps(0)) is active . Swapping the order of the tabs doesn't seem to change this effect either.

To give an example of what is happening to the styling, here is what the `Tab` component should have for its styling:

```
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    display: inline-flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Roboto","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    line-height: 1.25;
    letter-spacing: 0.02857em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    max-width: 360px;
    min-width: 90px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 48px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: #1976d2;
```

But when you change to another `Tab` it usually becomes something like:

```
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Roboto","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    line-height: 1.25;
    letter-spacing: 0.02857em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    max-width: 360px;
    min-width: 90px;
    min-height: 48px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: normal;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    color: inherit;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    user-select: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

Any insight onto how/why this is happening would help immensely.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to access the styles of MUI components.  I'll drop a few of my preferred approaches.  These methods are derived from the MUI documentation on [theming](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/) and [customization](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/).

### Method #1: Use Theme Colors

The easiest is if you want to change it to another color within your theme palette.  The properties `indicatorColor` and `textColor` allow you the values of `primary`, `secondary`, and `inherit` (in the case of `textColor`) ([see the api doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tabs/)).

I try to stick to this method, if possible, as it keeps my sites looking uniform in their color palettes.

With the default theme, these settings:

```js
<Tabs
  {... tabsProps}
  indicatorColor="secondary"
  textColor="inherit"
>
```

... will make it look like this:

[image]

You will need to create a custom theme if you want to have specific colors using this method.

### Method #2: Use The `styled()` Utility

If you inspect the DOM in your browser, you'll see that it will have a CSS class and property something like this:

```
.css-[some random string]-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiTab-root.Mui-selected {
    color: [the theme.palette.primary.main color];
}
.css-[some random string]-MuiTabs-indicator {
    background-color: [the theme.palette.primary.main color];
}
```

These give you a clue on where to look within the documentation to customize your tabs.  In this case `MuiTab` for the text color and `MuiTabs` for the indicator color.  Also, looking at the API docs for each of these components will give you the CSS class names to access the properties of the components; in our case `Mui-selected` for the `Tab` component and `MuiTabs-indicator` for the `Tabs` component.

Creating a styled Mui component:

```
const CustomTabs = styled(Tabs)(() => ({
  '& .MuiTabs-indicator': {
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
}))

const CustomTab = styled(Tab)(() => ({
  '&.Mui-selected': {
    color: "red",
  }
}))

[...]

<CustomTabs
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
>
  <CustomTab label="Item One" />
  <CustomTab label="Item Two" />
  <CustomTab label="Item Three" />
</CustomTabs>
```

I dropped a CodeSandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/customize-mui-tab-color-ftlp22?file=/demo.js).

There are some other methods to customize things.  Just take a look at the MUI customization and theming docs if you need details.